# Wordpress Global product return only title

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I use WordPress and woocommerce plugin and try to show header part of page 393, and after her to show the content of the current product.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product', 'get_header_work_portfolio' );

function get_header_work_portfolio() { global $product;

echo '<div class="row">   <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 mt10pr">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">show me</div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8">';
      //here must show description of product
    echo '</div>   </div> </div>';
```

and here i show title part of page 393: 
in **single-product.php**:

```
$id=393;
$post = get_post($id);
$content = apply_filters('the_content', $post->post_content);
echo $content;
```

when I try to call `$product` in function.php it returns the only title of product ... I want to get only a description of the current product...

Comment: Try this  $product = wc_get_product( id );

echo $product->get_the_content();

Comment: ` Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_ID() on string` i can not catch the product id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove this code from `single-product.php`

```
$id=393;    
$content = get_the_content($id);
$content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);
```

becouse the wordpress catch this id , and all is crashed ...

install plugin `insert pages` and add shortcode of page in single-products.php like this
echo do_shortcode("[insert page='page-slag' display='all|content|title']");